# How to do quickly React Native ConnectyCube Videochat?

Tags: react-native

React native [ConnectyCube Videochat onCallListener](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling) doesn't work quickly.

```
ConnectyCube.videochat.onCallListener = function (session, extension) {};
```

Please help me to do quickly React Native ConnectyCube VideoChat onCallListener?

Comment: What do you mean by "do it quickly"?

Comment: I mean that React Native ConnectyCube.videochat.onCallListener works very slow and how to fix to work quickly?